# Centering in dcases environment

Tags: mathtools

How would I go about centering the zero within the column for the following dcases MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    T  =
\begin{dcases}
    0 &, \text{ if A, or} \\
    \frac{1.0}{1.0 + X} &, \text{ if B, or} \\
    \frac{X}{1.0 + X} &, \text{ if C}
\end{dcases} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

i.e. instead of the produced [image: the produced],

I want it to look like this [image: like this]

I have found previous posts describing centering in a cases environment, but I haven't been able to get them to work in dcases

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't do it, but if you really want to, you have to fix the wrong definition of `dcases` made in `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\renewcommand{\dcases}
 {
  \MT_start_cases:nnnn
    {\quad}
    {$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil}
    {$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil}
    {\lbrace}
 }
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    T  =
\begin{dcases}
    \hfil 0 & \text{, if A, or} \\
    \frac{1.0}{1.0 + X} &\text{, if B, or} \\
    \frac{X}{1.0 + X} &\text{, if C}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The original definition has `\displaystyle{##}` which is simply wrong.

I'd avoid the commas hanging from nowhere too.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The low level `\omit` helps. It removes the original format of the cell. Then the cell is centered manually by adding `\hfil` on both sides. Also the math mode needs to be set. Also `dcases` uses `\displaystyle`, but that does not matter for a simple digit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    T  =
\begin{dcases}
    \omit\hfil$0$\hfil &, \; \text{ if A, or} \\
    \frac{1.0}{1.0 + X} &, \; \text{ if B, or} \\
    \frac{X}{1.0 + X} &, \; \text{ if C}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: worked like a charm for my use, even if @egreg's is more general

Answer (score 5):

Of course, an `array` can also help in adjusting your horizontal alignment if the defaults don't suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,colortbl}
\setlength{\minrowclearance}{5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  T =
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}c@{\quad,\quad}l}
              0         & \text{if $A$, or} \\
    \dfrac{1.0}{1.0 + X} & \text{if $B$, or} \\
     \dfrac{X}{1.0 + X}  & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```